# Why the function is O(2n^3) and not O(n^3)?

Tags: big-o

I am currently reading an algorithms book and wondering why the following function has O(2n^3) and not O(n^3)

```
f(n) = 2n^3 - 2n^2
```

If we took c = 2 and n0 = 1 then g(n) is just n^3

Comment: `2n^3` **IS** `n^3` for large values of `n`. `$n^3` makes no sense.

Comment: I don't understand. If you are saying 2n^3 is n^3 then why n^3 makes no sense ?

Comment: `$n^3` (note the **$** sign) makes no sense.

Comment: Oh sorry I corrected it. so both 2n^3 and n^3 are correct ?

Comment: Surely it's O(n^3) no?

Comment: n^3 is correct, 2n^3 less-so. O() notation only wants "variable" terms. `2` is irrelevant for large values of n

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because as `n` gets larger the impact of `n²` becomes less and less significant as `n³`, which grows `n` times faster, dwarfs it.

We ignore the lower orders, and so in this case we ignore the `n²`, and indeed the constant multipliers `2`.

Comment: Yeah I know we should ignore the constant multipliers and the lower orders. That is why it was weird to see the answer in the book is 2n^3